# How canI continue a windows phone application if I am not logged out?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

How can I continue my windows phone application, if I have not logged out?

Thanks.

```
    private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string uname = txtname.Text;
            string pwd = txtpwd.Password;

            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Session"] = uname;
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();

            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/details.xaml?uname=" + txtname.Text + "&pwd=" + txtpwd.Password+ "", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Comment: You have logged out from?

Comment: No, If I have not logged out, and at some point I press windows key or exit application, now I want that whenever I start application, it should continue from that point.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where are you logged in?

Comment: OK,see by eample:
I run the application and logged in with default navigation page "Login.xaml".
Now after login I got the details page,now I exit app without logging out, and I click on that app and I want that details page to continue.
Thanks!

Comment: So you want to be logged when you start again your application? (the last log-in session?)

Comment: yes,I want to be logged and I want that page from where I left.
Thanks!!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967547(v=vs.105).aspx for best practice on how to handle deactivation.
new for WP8: fast app resume. see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for persistent storage, A storage which persists even when theuser exits from the app, I answered your last question with the use of static variable but static variable never persists after relaunch, and for that you need to use IsolatedSotageSettings

Sample storage and retrieval

```
 //storage, you shall do it on login, Just put a variable, maybe user name
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Session"] = Name;
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();

 //retrieval on every pages loaded or onnavigated to event to check for the session
 if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("Session") == true)
 {
 var object= IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Session"] as string;
 }
 else
 {
  //session expired
 }
 //Removal of session
 if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("Session") == true)
 {
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("Session");
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
 }
```

Now when you come to the app after exiting, On login page loaded/OnNavigatedTo Event just put a check like this

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
 if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("Session") == true)
 {
  //Session exists
  //navigate to next page then
 }
 else
 {
  //session expired
 }
}
```

In the same way you could store a complete user defined object in IsolatedStorageSettings.

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) link too

Comment: Where should I write this code and Thanks for your reply brother.

Comment: when user logs in, that is, when the button for logging in is pressed there you should save the session(first two lines of code). Now once this object is saved it doesn't gets deleted till you don't delete it in code or uninstall the app. And on pressing log out you shall put the last if condition which removes the session object. That's it.

Comment: yes you are doing it right, where is the problem then

Comment: but every time I exit app without log out and click on app the login page appears.Thanks!!

Comment: you need to check the value on login and then do the actions accordingly. Just check the edits I made.

Answer (score 0):

```
void RootFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        reset = (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Reset);
    }


    void RootFrame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (reset && e.IsCancelable && e.Uri.OriginalString == "/Login.xaml")
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            reset = false;
        }
    }
```

write down this code in your App.XAML in Private void InitializePhoneApplication(),
RootFrame.Navigating += RootFrame_Navigating and
RootFrame.Navigated += RootFrame_Navigated